# Basic definition of meagre set

Tags: general-topology

I am reading Elias Zakon's Mathematical Analysis II. To, it gives a non-standard definition of residual, which is: "a set $A$ is residual iff $S−A$ is meagre, but $A$ is not. (S is a complete metric space)" In other textbooks, it only requires $S-A$ to be meagre, but there are not requirement for A to be non-meagre. So my first question is: are these two definitions equivalent?

My second question is related to the following execise problem, which is closely related to the above definition: "Prove that if $K$ is a $G_\delta$-set, and if $K$ is dense in a complete metric space $(S,\rho)$, i.e., $\bar{K}=S$, then $K$ is residual in $S$." To me it is easy to verify that $-K$ is meagre, but how to verify $K$ is non-meagre?

Comment: I published in the past several papers related to this topic but I never bothered to master the definitions except the definition of the dense set. ##### Just put some effort and provide the relevant definitions straight in your "Question". (Even your -A looks awkward).

Comment: The extra clause "but $A$ is not" becomes redundant iff the whole space isn't meager. The Baire category theorem says that a complete metric space is never meager.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space. Also, if you don't mind, can you please edit your question to use more standard notation for the complement of a set?

Comment: Thanks you all for the helpful answer.